# Getting list of all entries in the Firefox chrome registry

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

Is it possible to get a list of all entries from the Chrome registry along with their actual physical mapping? For example, I am looking for a list like this:

> chrome://browser/content/browser.xul   [actual physical path]
>   chrome://browser/content/browser.js
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...
>   chrome://some_extension/content/overlay.xul   jar:file:///path/to/extension/

Is there some data structure that maps these entries in the chrome/src/ directory source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping is performed by the [`nsIChromeRegistry` component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIChromeRegistry), it processes all the manifest files and creates rules by which `chrome://` URLs are being resolved. These rules aren't exposed, already because they are more complicated than what you apparently expect. E.g. a [`content` instruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#section_15) tells the chrome registry how to resolve any URL starting with `chrome://foo/content/` - the registry only knows the prefix but not the individual files. Handling of [locales](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#section_16) and [skins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#section_17) is similar but has a complication - there might be more than one locale/skin and how the URL is resolved depends on the current locale/skin of the browser. Finally, it is possible to [override individual URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#override) and for example redirect them to other `chrome://` URLs.

So all you have is [nsIChromeRegistry.convertChromeURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIChromeRegistry#convertChromeURL%28%29) that will resolve a `chrome://` URL and give you a different URL (`file://`, `jar:` or even another `chrome://` URL).

Now if you had access to **private** properties of [`nsChromeRegistryChrome` class](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/cb01e23f83cf/chrome/src/nsChromeRegistryChrome.cpp), e.g. by patching up that class - then things would be different. The member variable you are interested in is `mPackagesHash`. The hash keys are package names, the values have type `PackageEntry`. There is also `mOverrideHash` containing the overrides. Something like this should work (code is untested of course):

```c++
mOverrideTable.EnumerateRead(&PrintOverride, nsnull);

PL_DHashTableEnumerate(&mPackagesHash,
                       &nsChromeRegistryChrome::PrintPackage,
                       nsnull);

...

PLDHashOperator
PrintOverride(nsIURI* key,
              nsIURI* uri,
              void* closure)
{
  nsCString keySpec;
  nsresult rv = key->GetSpec(&keySpec);
  if (NS_SUCCEEDED(rv))
  {
    nsCString spec;
    rv = uri->GetSpec(&spec);
    if (NS_SUCCEEDED(rv))
      printf("override %s %s\n", keySpec.get(), spec.get());
  }

  return PL_DHASH_NEXT;
}

PLDHashOperator
nsChromeRegistryChrome::PrintPackage(PLDHashTable *table,
                                     PLDHashEntryHdr *hdr,
                                     PRUint32 number,
                                     void *closure)
{
  PackageEntry* package = static_cast<PackageEntry*>(entry);

  nsCString spec;
  nsresult rv = entry->baseURI->GetSpec(&spec);
  if (NS_SUCCEEDED(rv))
    printf("content %s %s\n", entry->package.get(), spec.get());

  nsTArray<nsCString> locales;
  entry->locales.EnumerateToArray(&locales);
  for (PRUint32 i = locales.Length(); i > 0 ; ) {
    i--;
    nsCOMPtr<nsIURI> uri = entry->locales.GetBase(locales[i], nsProviderArray::EXACT);
    rv = uri->GetSpec(&spec);
    if (NS_SUCCEEDED(rv))
      printf("locale %s %s %s\n", entry->package.get(), locales[i].get(), spec.get());
  }

  nsTArray<nsCString> skins;
  entry->skins.EnumerateToArray(&skins);
  for (PRUint32 i = skins.Length(); i > 0 ; ) {
    i--;
    nsCOMPtr<nsIURI> uri = entry->skins.GetBase(skins[i], nsProviderArray::EXACT);
    rv = uri->GetSpec(&spec);
    if (NS_SUCCEEDED(rv))
      printf("skin %s %s %s\n", entry->package.get(), skins[i].get(), spec.get());
  }

  return PL_DHASH_NEXT;
}
```

**Edit**: As of Firefox 28, there is now a better way. [Bug 890545](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=890545) introduced the (not yet documented) `nsIComponentManager.getManifestLocations()` method, it returns an [nsIArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIArray) instance listing the [URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIURI) of each active [chrome manifest file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration). So something like that would work to get the text of all manifest files:

```js
var locations = Components.manager.getManifestLocations();
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
{
  var uri = locations.queryElementAt(i, Components.interfaces.nsIURI);
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", uri.spec, false);
  try
  {
    request.send(null);
    parseManifest(uri, request.responseText); // Something for you to implement
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    Components.utils.reportError(e);
  }
}
```

Still, parsing the manifests is something you would have to do yourself in that scenario, in particular the [manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration#manifest), [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration#content) and [override](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration#override) lines - all in all not exactly a simple task, especially if you consider the flags correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I have looked into the nsChromeRegistry. I think Mozilla uses a combination of Hashtables and Arrays to manage the mappings. What I was trying to say is whether I could get a list of all such mappings from these data structures (querying the data structures at runtime, say, after all chromes have been mapped). There was an add-on named ChromeList that did that. Sadly, it doesn't work in the new Firefox.

Comment: @Anton: That extension parses the manifests "manually", it cannot access the internal structures of the chrome registry either.

Comment: Ya, I know. However, I am trying to introduce some debugging code(not patch) in the Firefox source code. That's why I need to understand those internal data structures.

Comment: @Anton: Ok, I've edited my answer and added approximate code that you would use if you were able to patch up `nsChromeRegistryChrome`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was actually coding a crude version of this right now, but your code looks a lot better!

Comment: Not sure if I understand this topic right, but just to note cause I think its related: there may be now a `getManifestLocations()`, (via [Issue 46 - chromelist - Does not work with Firefox4](https://code.google.com/p/chromelist/issues/detail?id=46) -> [bugzilla #890545 – Provide a way to enumerate registered manifests](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=890545))

Comment: @sdaau: Thank you, I edited my answer to include this approach.